# Using lists created in a constructor in a separate method

Tags: java, list, constructor

I have created and initialized variables inside a constructor.
Is there any way to access these variables?

For example:

```
public Bicycle() {
int gear = 1;
int cadence = 10;
int speed = 0;
```

}

After declaring a Bicycle object

```
Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle();
```

Can I access the variable gear and its value?

In my code I have Lists instead of ints, but I figured this would be a similar enough question to ask. If there is any difference in accessing Lists, please let me know in your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to access the gear variable outside of that constructor because `gear` is a local variable there (i.e. it's declared *inside* the constructor). You might want to make `gear` (and `cadence` and `speed`) fields of the `Bicycle` class so that you can access then from any method of that class. (The same applies for instances of `List`).

```
public class Bicyle {
    // Notice we're declaring the variables outside the constructors, as fields.
    int gear;
    int cadence;
    int speed;

    public Bicycle() {
        // The variables are initialized (but not declared) here
        gear = 1;
        cadence = 10;
        speed = 0;
    }

    public someMethod() {
        //Accessing gear from outside constructor
        gear = gear + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is a basic concept in Object Oriented Programming, which you might want to research. To access these objects, you would normally create 'getters' and 'setters'. These are methods in your class that can get and set class variables like the ones you provide. I encourage you to look up these concepts because they are explained well all over the internet.

Comment: Nope.  These variables were declared in the scope of the constructor.  They're not fields.